# NetBeans Won't Change my Background Color

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, background

So, I'm like 15 minutes new to NetBeans, and I'm already having an issue. So, I just want to make a simple GUI, and I've got all that good, except for the background. I want the background to be yellow, and as we can see here, it is:

[image: Window properties]

Those are the window properties. And in the code it confirms the RGB selection of mine with this line: `setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 55));`

However, when the window is launched, I get this:

[image: Application window]

Why is my choice of color not showing up in the background?

Comment: Which component are you setting the background on? Is it set as `opaque`? Are there layered panels/frames/whatever?

Answer (score 2):

based on [this link](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=130413):

Create a new project and insert a new JFrame. Go to the properties window and set the background property of JFrame form to red.
If you run the application now, the window just flashes red and then becomes gray again.

The reason is that a code generated in "initComponents" function is:

1) setBackground(new java.awt.Color(57, 214, 18));

But 99% of programmers would probably expect the behavior of code:

2) getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(57, 214, 18));

Simply, the JFrame is covered with some other container (content pane), so if you want to set up the background color
for the JFrame, you need to do it with writing code manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might create a JPanel, add it to the JFrame and set its background color.

```
Panel panel = new Panel(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
frame.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a panel on top of the jframe and changing the panel's background color worked for me.